# Elastic search - how to return last n entries?

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, axios

I'm new to working with elastic search so my understanding is fairly limited. For a project, using ReactJS, I need to return the latest n number of entries into a database, which changes each day. I'm currently returning all data and using slice(-n) on the frontend to solve the problem, but I appreciate this isn't ideal. This is what I'm currently posting:

```
return axios
    .post(
      `${url}/${db}/1`,
      {
        aggs: {
          sales_over_time: {
            date_histogram: {
              field: "date",
              calendar_interval: "day",
              format: "dd-MM-yyyy",
            },
          },
        },
      },

    )
    .then(({ data }) => {
      return data;
    });
```

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Do you want documents most recent?

Comment: @rabbitbr Yes, more than likely the last 7 documents to show the previous weeks sales data. I appreciate I have a working solution right now by bringing it all back and manipulating it on the frontend, but it's not a great solution and I'd like to learn.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can easily sort your **date_histogram** aggregation result using `order` parameter in your elasticsearch query.
2. Also you can slice the result of your aggregation either by providing the `size` parameter in sub aggregation of type **bucket_sort** or by using `range` in **filter** query.

Below is the elasticsearch query to do that -

```
{
  "aggs" : {
    "sales_over_time" : {
      "date_histogram" : {
        "order" : {
          "_key" : "desc"
        },
        "field" : "date",
        "calendar_interval":"day",
        "format" : "dd-MM-yyyy"
      },
      "aggs" : {
        "latest7" : {
          "bucket_sort" : {
            "size" : 7,
            "sort" : []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```